# Windows Server 2012 - remote gaming - RDP vGPU - Q about the limitations

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, remote-desktop, virtualization, windows-server-2012

I want to play games through lan, on my laptop. Ran by the other powerhouse.
This, in theory, works. RemoteFX especially if virtualized by Server 2012, can do this.
(I have a DX11 card, a required CPU and all the other requirements.)

But I do have questions regarding all this.

- Can a local user also play games? Or 1 card means 1 guest with vGPU?
  (local = logged in admin account to Server 2012)
- Could two users (using Concurrent RDP patch) play games on a server by logging in with two users?
- Or can I run a second Windows 7 / 8 guest to run the games for the other person?

I could also plug in a second GPU, so one person could game on the Server itself, and the other one could get the vGPU with the second card. But can I do this? Is it possible?

You can imagine the setup. Two users want to play games, but the laptop is terrible.

**PS:** The current RDP update for Windows 7 only allows you to use the features provided  by the Server 2012/2008R2. The Windows 7 RDP server itself won't allow you to play games. (There is no vGPU.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brian. To anyone else who is curious (like I was): Performance is choppy even with a top-tier GPU (7870OC pushed 10-20 fps in Unigine / low). Not to mention there is a mouse lag which won't let you play any games (any FPS/TPS ones for example). So RemoteFX/vGPU is an awesome technology, but it's not for gaming. (No one said it was.) I used Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8 Enterprise + Windows 7 x64 Enterprise guests. (I had to vomit all along due to the silly apps/tiles, even on 2012. Jesus. Ballmer, get yourself together.) So, that's it. Feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far as I know remote desktop into the server doesn't work for this. You must remote desktop into a guest machine on the server that has all the RemoteFX / vGPU etc enabled. This guest needs to be the Enterprise Edition of either Windows 7 or Windows 8.

Several virtual machines can use the same physical GPU as a vGPU.

More information: [RemoteFX vGPU Setup and Configuration Guide for Windows Server 2012](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16652.remotefx-vgpu-setup-and-configuration-guide-for-windows-server-2012.aspx)